# My Display Mode doesn't seem to be working

Tags: math-mode

I want to have this summation display in display mode but I am getting errors saying that a $ is missing even though adding one doesn't fix anything.

This is the code I have

```
\begin{tabbing}

\ $M_x(s)=E_x[e^{sx}], \ s\epsilon R$\\
\textbf{Discrete} \\
\ \[M_x(s)=\sum_{x\epsilon X}e^{sx}P_x(x)\] \\

\end{tabbing}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Why does the tabbing environment come into play here? Could you post a sketch of what you're trying to obtain?

Comment: you can't have a display environment in tabbing, you could use `$\displaystyle ....$`

Comment: but you appear to be using tabbing without setting any tab stops, what is the intention of tabbing here?

Comment: This was my first time using Latex and I just wanted to make every new line start on the same tab. The \displaystyle actually worked thank you!

Comment: Do not using `tabbing` it is almost never the right approach (I have used latex for 30 years and used it at most a couple of times)

Comment: How would you recommend I keep all my lines on the same tab. Before when I would hit enter and type a new line it would automatically tab it and I couldn't do \- to remove the tab.

Comment: it's hard to know what you want with such a small example, displayed equations are centred by default, if you want them left aligned then use `\documentclass[fleqn]{article}` to specify flush left equations.